# update join table has_many through with additional checkboxes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

if i dont find solution here i have no idea where i should looking for...

I know there is right, easy solution for it...but something i just dont understand.

I have 3 models...

*Scheme.rb*

```
class Scheme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :custom_issue_field_definitions, through: :scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions
  has_many :scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions
end
```

*CustomIssueFieldDefinition.rb*

```
class CustomIssueFieldDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schemes, through: :scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions
  has_many :scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions
  belongs_to :custom_issue_field
end
```

*SchemeCustomIssueFieldDefinition.rb*

```
class SchemeCustomIssueFieldDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scheme
  belongs_to :custom_issue_field_definition
end
```

Join Model have 3 additional fields...with type: boolean.

[image]

---

### I'd like to update scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions table. How controller and form should looks like?

Additional image:
[image]

Update:

In console i can update it like this:

```
a = Scheme.first
b = CustomIssueFieldDefinition.first
c = a.scheme_custom_issue_field_defintitions.find_or_create_by(custom_issue_field_definition: b)
c.update_attributes(visible: 1, reportable: 0, required: 0)
```

Next Update:

Now form looks like this (what is completely wrong):

```
<%= simple_form_for @scheme_new_custom_issue_field, url: configurations_scheme_path(@scheme), method: :put do |f| %>
      <% @available_custom_issue_field_definitions.each do |custom_issue_field| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= custom_issue_field.label %></td>
            <td><%= f.input :visible, as: :boolean %></td>
            <td><%= f.input :reportable, as: :boolean %></td>
            <td><%= f.input :required, as: :boolean %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

and schemes_controller

```
def update
    @scheme = Scheme.find(params[:id])
    @scheme_new_custom_issue_field = @scheme.scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions.
      find_or_create_by(scheme_id: @scheme, custom_issue_field_definition_id: params[:custom_issue_field_definition_id])
    if @scheme_new_custom_issue_field.update_attributes(scheme_custom_issue_field_definition_params)
      flash[:success] = "Scheme has been successfully updated"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Update Solution: 
[image]

Comment: What is the Db visualizer you are using? Just curious

Comment: Its MySql Workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create new `SchemCustomIssueFieldDefinition` record in the console, I suggest this alternative:

```
a = Scheme.first
b = CustomIssueFieldDefinition.first
c = SchemeCustomIssueFieldDefinition.find_or_initialize_by(scheme: a, custom_issue_field_definition: b)
c.assign_attributes(visible: 1, reportable: 0, required: 0)
c.save
```

This will save you one less query than your current example code as this will not do have an UPDATE sql.

For your form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @scheme, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <% @available_custom_issue_field_definitions.each do |custom_issue_field| %>
    <tr> 
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions, @scheme.scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions.find_or_initialize_by(custom_issue_field_definition: custom_issue_field) do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :scheme_id, value: @scheme.id %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :custom_issue_field_definition_id, value: custom_issue_field.id %>
        <td><%= custom_issue_field.label %></td>
        <td><%= ff.input :visible, as: :boolean %></td>
        <td><%= ff.input :reportable, as: :boolean %></td>
        <td><%= ff.input :required, as: :boolean %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

schemes_controller.rb:

```
class SchemesController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def update
    @scheme = Scheme.find(params[:id])
    if @scheme.update(scheme_params)
      flash[:success] = "Scheme has been successfully updated"
      redirect_to :back
    else
     render :edit
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

  def scheme_params
    # update below if you need other scheme attributes to be updated
    params.require(:scheme).permit(:id, scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions_attributes: [:id, :scheme_id, :custom_issue_field_definition_id, :visible, :reportable, :required])
  end
end
```

scheme.rb

```
class Scheme < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions_attributes
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Hmm...i have checked answer...but something went wrong...Dont forget i want to save visible on appropriate record...so "visible" have to know where it want to be saved. `ff.input :visible` give me wrong output

Comment: yes the "visible" attribute in my answer in the form above, is associated to a record of type "scheme_custom_issue_field_definition". In which you are creating/updating multiple "scheme_custom_issue_field_definition" record for each of the `@available_custom_issue_field_definitions` that you specified. This means you can check/uncheck that "visible" attribute in the form, and the record that it will point to is @scheme -> scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions. This is what `fields_for` is used for (it builds form elements for the associated record/s). What was the error?

Comment: You said `so "visible" have to know where it want to be saved`, but yes visible already knows where it wants to be saved (if the record exists / create one if not yet exist). See this line in my answer above:  `<%= f.simple_form_for :scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions, @scheme.scheme_custom_issue_field_definitions.find_or_initialize(custom_issue_field_definition: custom_issue_field) do |ff| %>` It looks for the already created record or initialize it if not yet existing.

Comment: Oh i know now. There was a typo in my form. See my updated answer above should be f.simple_fields_for and not f.simple_form_for

Comment: hmm now looks better...(i didnt understand why did you put form in form)...but now i have error: `undefined method `find_or_initialize' for #<SchemeCustomIssueFieldDefinition::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fee3246d5c0>`

Comment: ok i change it to `find_or_initialize_by` but now i have error: "undefined method merge for 8:Fixnum" and show this line:  `<%= ff.hidden_field :scheme_id, @scheme.id %>`

Comment: I updated my answer. I think the `value: ` will do the trick.

Comment: ok fast update: its simple form so i change it to :  `<%= ff.input :id, as: :hidden %>
        <%= ff.input :scheme_id, value: @scheme.id, as: :hidden%>
        <%= ff.input :custom_issue_field_definition_id, value: custom_issue_field.id, as: :hidden %>` and now display page properly :) lets test :)

Comment: omg it works....update work properly...screenshot from console on put method above...and i your a genius...its right answer.

Comment: `hidden_field` will actually also work for simple_form. But if you really want a simple_form version, you need it to be like the following `<%= ff.input :schema_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: @schema.id} %>`

Comment: Thank you so much...you are really perfect.